# Minecraft - Is there an ingame way to learn how to build a nether portal

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does the game ever teach/show you how to craft a nether portal? Or is it something you are just supposed to look up. I know the wither is "foreshadowed" by that one painting, so you could potentially learn how to summon it through that. However I cant find anything similar for the portal.

Comment: You could suggest it on the feedback site. Click the "leave feedback" button in the game's menu to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually no, it doesn't exist. The closest would be one of the paintings showing a nether portal (but in awful resolution), I think. There's no in-game mechanic that creates one for the player to learn that it exists, or tell the player how to create one.

Comment: There's also the advancement, "We Need to Go Deeper" - "Build, light and enter a Nether Portal", it follows the advancement of obtaining obsidian and it has flint&iron as an icon. These are very vague hints and it still doesn't suggest what shape/size the portal would need to be in the slightest.